# Array.contains returns false

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, contains

I have an array of users `[User]` called conversationUsers

User is defined as

```
public class User: NSManagedObject { ... }
```

and `currUser` is an User object

if I try

```
currUser == conversationUsers[0]
```

it results **true**

but

```
conversationUsers.contains(currUser)
```

results **false**

If instead I use

```
conversationUsers.contains({$0 == currUser})
```

it returns **true**

FYI I have also defined this:

```
public func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {

    let logicalExpression = lhs.email.lowercaseString == rhs.email.lowercaseString

    return logicalExpression

}
```

---

Why contains returns false? Which is his default predicate?

Thank you for your help

Comment: is `conversationUsers` an array of `User` objects explicitly? ie: `[User]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

In short, you should override `NSObject.isEqual()` method:

```
public class User: NSManagedObject { 
    ... 
    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let rhs = object as? User {
            return self == rhs
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

I made a little research. It seems that if class `A` is inherited from `NSObject` then collection methods like `contains` use `NSObject.isEqual()` method for determining equality of two objects. Class `B` is not inherited from `NSObject` so `contains` method is working as expected.

```
import Foundation

class A: NSObject {
    var value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}

var a = A(1)
var array: [A] = [a, A(2)]
array.contains(a) // true
array.contains(A(1)) // false
array.contains { $0 == A(1) } // true
array[0] == A(1) // true


class B: Equatable {
    var value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

func ==(lhs: B, rhs: B) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}

var b = B(1)
var array2: [B] = [b, B(2)]
array2.contains(b) // true
array2.contains(B(1)) // true
array2.contains { $0 == B(1) } // true
array2[0] == B(1) // true
```

So you need to override `NSObject.isEqual()` method:

```
class A: NSObject {
    var value: Int

    init(_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        if let rhs = object as? A {
            return self == rhs
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

`User` class should also conform to `Equatable` protocol:

```
extension User: Equatable {}
```

Or you can add it directly to class definition:

```
public class User: NSManagedObject, Equatable {}
```

Comment: I had already done but not necessary, Xcode signals an error: 
" Redundant conformance of 'User' to protocol 'Equatable'.
User inherits conformance to protocol 'Equatable' from superclass here "

Comment: How is `conversationUsers` array declared?

Comment: var conversationUsers:[User] = []  
...and then populated like this:
  conversationUsers = conversation.participants.allObjects as! [User] 
where participants is a NSSet of a conversation who is an object inheriting from NSManagedObject

Comment: So `conversation.participants.allObjects` is not array of `User`? Casting it to `[User]` does not make it array of `User` objects so your `func==` does not work for them.

Comment: Yes they are User objects but saved and managed as NSSet because CoreData... if `func==` does not work why `conversationUsers.contains({$0 == currUser})` do?

Comment: I do not know. Is `func==` defined at global scope (not in class)?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now is clear why it happens... the problem now is that is not explicitly allowed to override NSManagedObject -isEqual but I think the question is well answered.

Comment: Yep, I think that it's better not to mess with `Equatable` and `NSObject.isEqual` at all in this case and implement your own `User.isEqualToUser(user: User)` method and call it like `conversationUsers.contains { $0.isEqualToUser(currUser) }`